# Cannot bring all the element from html to docx that have same tag with java

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, docx, mammoth

I have a project converting from html to docx with java, in the html document I have 2 paragraph with 2 header as a title, but when converting both of them to docx format, just one paragraph that successfully converted, but the other paragraph doesn't converted even they have same tag. Look the image below

[image: Click Image for Detail]

And the code look like this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import static org.apache.poi.hslf.model.textproperties.TextPropCollection.TextPropType.paragraph;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.VerticalAlign;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.zwobble.mammoth.DocumentConverter;
import org.zwobble.mammoth.Result;

/**
 *
 * @author Alwan
 */

public class TestWord {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try
        {
            File file = new File("src/test/TEST.docx");
            DocumentConverter converter = new DocumentConverter();
            Result<String> result = converter.extractRawText(file);
            String html = result.getValue(); // The generated HTML
            Set<String> warnings = result.getWarnings(); // Any warnings during conversion

            String[] part = html.split("<p>");
            String[] part2 = html.split("<h1>");

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("testformat.docx"));
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

            XWPFRun paragraphOneRunOne = paragraph.createRun();            

            XWPFRun paragraphOneRunThree = paragraph.createRun();            

            for (int i = 0; i < html.length(); i++) 
            {
            if (i % 2 != 0) 
            {          
                paragraphOneRunOne.setBold(true);
                paragraphOneRunOne.setItalic(true);
                paragraphOneRunOne.setText(part[i].trim());
                paragraphOneRunOne.addBreak();

                paragraphOneRunThree.setStrike(true);
                paragraphOneRunThree.setFontSize(20);
                paragraphOneRunThree.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUBSCRIPT);
                paragraphOneRunThree.setText(part2[i].trim());

                System.out.println(part2[i].trim());
                System.out.println(part[i].trim());

                    doc.write(out);
                    out.close();
            }


            System.out.println("testformat.docx written successully");
            }
            System.out.println("Success");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }

}
```

The question is, how to bring all the paragraph from html into the docx format when its have a same tag? Thank you for your attention before. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What happens when you remove the `if (i % 2 != 0)` conditional?

Comment: It will read the entire of array, while the rule of this code is just read the odd array index to make it work. So i give that conditions.